# Unable to work out simple helloworld example of KnockOut

Tags: knockout.js

I was trying to use knockout but despite the very simple code i am unable to get the select list populated.
Below is the code, can anybody point out what am i doing wrong

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.3.0.js">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var listEditorViewModel = function () {
        this.allItems = ko.observableArray(["Apple"]);
        }
        ko.applyBindings(document.body,new listEditorViewModel());
    </script>
    <div>This Select will be populated</div>
    <select multiple="multiple" data-bind="options: allItems"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter order in `applyBindings` is incorrect - first parameter must be model and second parameter is DOM element. Update your code like this:

```
ko.applyBindings(new listEditorViewModel(), document.body);
```

Or just omit the second parameter, because you are binding to all document anyway:

```
ko.applyBindings(new listEditorViewModel());
```